# no matching function for call Error while Passing a pointer to a constructor

Tags: c++, pointers

It might be a C++ beginner mistake but I'm really confused now by getting this compiler Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'B::B(A (*)())'
note: candidates are: B::B(A*)
```

I have written two class which look simplified like this:

```
//a very simple class A
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        //do some stuff in Constructor
    }
}

//another class, that stores a pointer to an object of A as a field
class B
{
private:
    A* _a;

public:
    //simply initialize the field in Constructor
    B(A* a) : _a(a) { }

    void doMagic()
    {
        //do something with _a
        _a->xyz();
    }
}
```

And what I am calling in my code is this:

```
A a();
B b(&a); //here the error appears
```

What I want is to create an object a and pass its pointer to object b. So that I have access to a in b's members.

It must be just something in the call of B b(&a); Perhaps you can find out what my Problem is very easily.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A a();
```

defines a function with the name `a` that returns an object of type `A`.
You are passing that function to the constructor of type `B`.

Change the initialization of `a` to this so that you create an object of type a:

```
A a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating an object of type `A`, instead, `A a();` is a declaration of function, which takes no parameter, and the return type is `A`. So you're trying to pass a function pointer to the ctor of `B`, that's what compiler complains. You should change

```
A a();
```

to

```
A a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A a();
```

This is a function declaration. The rule is: Everything which can be a function declaration is a function declaration.
This could be either constructor call or function declaration, tho it will never become a constructor call.
Try this instead:

```
A a;
```